# Можно ли не ставить тире на месте эллипсиса?

Tags: пунктуация

> Будь повнимательнее при оформлении текстов. После запятой или точки один пробел.

В этом предписании пропущено слово "делается". Допустимо ли не ставить тире?

Comment: Это предложение без контекста выглядит одиноко и потерянно. Иногда контекст для ответа необязателен, но что вы думаете  о вашем случае?

Answer (score 3):

*Будь повнимательнее при оформлении текстов. **После запятой или точки одИн пробел**.*

В данном случае тире можно не ставить. Ударением выделено сказуемое, а в этом случае  пауза после подлежащего отсутствует.